# Redis - Moving from IIS session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to understand how to implement redis by replacing all IIS session state values with the redis cache. I have redis working using a docker image. I am using a C# .Net Forms web app. I have included the StackExchange.Redis nuget package and set this up so far.

```
public class Redis
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {

        var redisConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisConnectionString"];
        var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(redisConnectionString);
        options.AbortOnConnectFail = false;

        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => LazyConnection.Value;
}
```

But I am confused how to store the user context session key value pairs. By this I mean when I store a key for the user, say "UserId" can the key just be "UserId"? or do I needs to prefix it with a unique user specific context id. I cant find anything on how redis would work based on different users. How does it know the context of the user and hence how to get the correct key?

All I'm reading is that its a hashtable that stores values, which is fine for a single UserId, but I'm going to have lots of users with a UserId?

If anyone can help me understand this, that would be great, thanks you

Comment: If you do it manually directly to Redis you need to have some way to manage a session identifier and use that in the keys. Otherwise you have no idea what is what and will overwrite things. But if you use the already provided session state provider for Redis then just use the ASP.NET state and the framework will handle everything for you

Comment: I am using the StackExchanage.Redis nuget package, so will that be doing the magic?

Comment: No, that will just provide direct access to Redis. Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider should be what you want

Comment: Ok so the only problem with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider is that it says it wont scale out if we need that. So presume I have to create a unique key if we want to scale out

Comment: Any built in state provider needs a shared key to work in a horizontally scaled environment. They need to have access to the data and it’s encrypted based on the shared key.

Comment: Ok so I misread/got confused reading the options at the bottom of that document, seemed confusing to have that. Ok so Ill focus on trying to get the shared key and then it should work in a distributed manner and scale out. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so after looking at the following link I was able to get it all working

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider

1. I installed a redis docker image as follows on the command line, replacing your **your_long_password_here**, you can also just specify port **6379:6379**, but I wanted to see what happens if I used another port. The password is important as otherwise it will run in protected mode which means only localhost(loopback) calls can be made, which helps protect it more, as pre version 3.2 this was not the case!

> ```
> docker run -p 8055:6379 --name redis --restart=always -d redis –-requirepass <your_long_password_here>
> ```

2. The run this command to make sure it was running, you should see that the port has the values you provided

> ```
> docker container ls
> ```

3. Then in your .net project install the following nuget packagefrom the nuget package manager console or use the GUI package manager. You will need to use .net 4.6.2 for the current version.

> ```
> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider
> ```

4. Once installed comment out or remove this line in your **Web.config**

> ```
> <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
> ```

5. Then update or change the new provider that the nuget package will have added to your **Web.config**. This should be inside the **system.web** tag. Note that I used a connection string as this will not be hosted on azure as of yet, but there are lots of confusing extra options to configure it.

> ```
> <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
>   <providers>
>   <add name="MySessionStateStore"
>        type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
>        connectionString="localhost:8055,password=your_long_password_here"/>
>   </providers>
> </sessionState>
> ```

6. You will need to make sure all the objects that you were storing in the iis session have the [Serializable] attribute as otherwise it wont work and will throw an error.

You should now see that you can run your website seamlessly, and you will now be using the redis cache and no longer the session state.